# Unable to get object from Controller to JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, dojo

I am trying to pass an object from Spring Controller to my JSP page and plan to iterate the object in JSP using JSTL. But I am unable to print the object in JSP. From the controller side, the value is sent successfully. I am thinking something is wrong in Javascript or JSP.

Request your valuable inputs. Pls find the code below,

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/changehistory/getSearchHistory.htm")
public ModelAndView getSearchHistory(@ModelAttribute(HISTORY_CRITERIA) HistoryCriteria historyCriteria,ModelMap model) {
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("changehistory/changeHistory_new");
     List<HistoryCriteriaResult> result=new ArrayList<HistoryCriteriaResult>();              
    result=changeHistoryService.getHistory(historyCriteria);
    mav.addObject("historyCriteriaResult", result);
    return mav;
}
```

JSP:

```
<div class="ItemListNavBoxLeft" style="margin-top: -2px; padding-left: 20px;"     
id="accordianRefreshBtn">

<div class="OrangeFB" style="width: auto; " onclick="RP.getSearchHistory()">
<div class="Q2"><div class="Q8"><div class="Q4"><div class="Q6"><div class="Q1"><div   
class="Q3"><div class="Q7"><div class="Q9"><div class="Q5">
                        &nbsp;<spring:message code='label.button.history'/>&nbsp;
            </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
        </div>

 <div id="changeHistorydiv" style="display:<c:choose><c:when 
 test='${fn:length(historyCriteriaResult) > }'>block</c:when>   
 <c:otherwise>none</c:otherwise></c:choose>;">
            <ul class="FormBody" style="padding-left:150px;">
                <li class="FormFieldTitle"></li>


                        id="RP.changeHist"
                        name="changeHist"> 

                        <c:forEach items="${historyCriteriaResult}" 
  var="HCList">
                                  ${HCList.code}
                              ${HCList.name}                            
                        </c:forEach>


            </ul>
        </div>
```

JS :

```
 RP.getSearchHistory = function() { 
     dojo.xhrPost({
        url : "/RMT/rateplan/getSearchHistory.htm?",
        timeout : 100000,       
        load : function(content) {
             var iList = content['result'], i;
             HCList.options.length = 0;     
             for (i = 0; i < iList.length; i++) {
                 HCList.options[HCList.options.length] = new Option(iList[i].name, iList[i].code);
             }          
        },
        error : function(error) {
            rmt.ErrorMessage.show(error);
        }
  });
 }
```

Comment: are you including <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> in your jsp?

Comment: yes, I have included it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Java variable `HCList` inside your JavaScript code, you have two options:

First you could return result in another JSP page and in this case you don't need to do `getSearchHistory` Ajax call, you can do this by defining another controller method in your controller class, check a form submission example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm), check how the controller class is implemented with two methods each one corresponded to a unique JSP file

Second, If you want return `historyCriteriaResult` in an AJAX request, then you must convert it to JSON format, so you need to change your Java method to something like this:

```
 @RequestMapping("/changehistory/getSearchHistory.htm")
 public @ResponseBody List<HistoryCriteriaResult> getSearchHistory(@ModelAttribute(HISTORY_CRITERIA) HistoryCriteria historyCriteria) {
     List<HistoryCriteriaResult> result=new ArrayList<HistoryCriteriaResult>();              
     result=changeHistoryService.getHistory(historyCriteria);
     return result;
 }
```

And in your JavaScript method you would parse the JSON response like this:

```
handleAs: "json",    // This force the response to be treated as JSON
load : function(content) {
         alert(content.HistoryCriteriaResultList[0].code);
         alert(content.HistoryCriteriaResultList[0].name);
         .
         .
         // or append it to any div you want
}
```

Note: If you are using Spring 3 or above, you need to add [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) JSON Parser to you project classpath

Comment: I took the first option and modified the controller to see the return result in another JSP page as follows.                    public ModelAndView getSearchHistory(@ModelAttribute(HISTORY_CRITERIA) HistoryCriteria historyCriteria,ModelMap model) {
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("changehistory/changeHistoryResults");
     List<HistoryCriteriaResult> result=new ArrayList<HistoryCriteriaResult>();              
    result=changeHistoryService.getHistory(historyCriteria);
    mav.addObject("historyCriteriaResult", result);
    return mav;
}

Comment: I tried putting into new JSP as below, but it did not work.  Am i missing something?  <div id="changeHistoryResults" dojoType="rmt.ContentPane" style="display:<c:choose><c:when test='${fn:length(historyCriteriaResult) > 0}'>block</c:when><c:otherwise>none</c:otherwise></c:choose>;"
        parseOnLoad="true"
        errorMessage="<spring:message code='error.genericError' />">        
                                 <jsp:include page="/changehistory/changeHistoryResults.htm" /> 
                                 
       </div>

Comment: I was not meaning by a new JSP moving the `forEach` loop in another JSP file, and just include it in the original JSP file, I mean defining a new JSP that returned on process request to retrieve the `historyCritera`, please check the answer, I have updated it